# Rust disallows disjoint mutable borrows in a mutating method

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership, lifetime-scoping

Consider the following abstract example (minimized from meaningful code):

```rust
struct Cucumber {
    vine: usize,
}

impl Cucumber {
    fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &mut usize> {
        Some(&mut self.vine).into_iter()
    }
    
    fn find_vine(&mut self) -> Option<&mut usize> {
        {
            let vines = self.iter_mut();
            for v in vines {
                if *v > 0 {
                    return Some(v);
                }
            }
        }
        self.vine = 1;
        None
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut c = Cucumber { vine: 0 };
    assert_eq!(c.find_vine(), None);
}
```

The compiler [complains](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=870b0946d306ab5b275ab77898187548) thus:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `self.vine` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:19:9
   |
10 |     fn find_vine(&mut self) -> Option<&mut usize> {
   |                  - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
11 |         {
12 |             let vines = self.iter_mut();
   |                         ---- `self.vine` is borrowed here
...
15 |                     return Some(v);
   |                            ------- returning this value requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'1`
...
19 |         self.vine = 1;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `self.vine` is assigned to here but it was already borrowed

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0506`.
error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to previous error
```

But, to my intuition, the borrow `vines` is already not live at the point where we assign to `self.vine`.
Could anyone hint, please, what is the problem here and is there a way to fix it without changing much the semantics of the code?

Comment: Oh yeah, compiling with `-Zpolonius` helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70779967/6187172