# Call a function that uses `&mut self.0` in a loop (E0499)

Tags: rust, reference, lifetime, mutable

I'm looking for a way around the *lack-of-polonius* problem *in this specific circumstance*. The other answers seem inapplicable, as far as I can understand at the moment.

I have two structures, `SourceBytes<S>` and `SourceChars`. The former is decoupled, but the second is heavily coupled to the former. `SourceBytes<S>` should be constructed from any `S: Iterator<Item = u8>`, and `SourceChars` should be constructed from the same, `S: Iterator<Item = u8>`.

This is what the definition looks like for each:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct SourceBytes<S>
where
    S: Iterator<Item = u8>,
{
    iter: S,
    buffer: Vec<S::Item>,
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct SourceChars<S>(S)
where
    S: Iterator<Item = u8>;
```

The purpose of `SourceBytes<S>` is to abstract over `S` so that each `S::Item` can be buffered, and be read immutably without taking/popping the item from the iterator. That looks like this:

```rust
impl<S> Iterator for SourceBytes<S>
where
    S: Iterator<Item = u8>,
{
    type Item = S::Item;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.buffer.pop().or_else(|| self.iter.next())
    }
}
```

This works fine, and the buffer is handled like so:

```rust
impl<S> SourceBytes<S>
where
    S: Iterator<Item = u8>,
{
    // pub fn new<I>(iter: I) -> Self
    // where
    //     I: IntoIterator<Item = S::Item, IntoIter = S>,
    // {
    //     Self {
    //         iter: iter.into_iter(),
    //         buffer: Vec::new(),
    //     }
    // }

    fn buffer(&mut self, count: usize) -> Option<&[u8]> {
        if self.buffer.len() < count {
            self.buffer
                .extend(self.iter.by_ref().take(count - self.buffer.len()));
        }
        self.buffer.get(0..count)
    }
}
```

So that each time `SourceBytes<S>::buffer` is called, the items will be taken from `S` and pushed to `buffer`. Each time `<SourceBytes as Iterator>::next` is called, it will first take from `self.buffer`, and then from `self.iter` where the type of the latter field is `S`.

Now, the purpose of `SourceChars<S>` is provide an `Iterator` interface to read bytes from `self.0` (which is `S`) until it finds a valid UTF-8 `char`, and then return it:

```rust
impl<S> Iterator for SourceChars<S>
where
    S: Iterator<Item = u8>,
{
    type Item = char;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let mut buf = [0; 4];
        // A single character can be at most 4 bytes.
        for (i, byte) in self.0.by_ref().take(4).enumerate() {
            buf[i] = byte;
            if let Ok(slice) = std::str::from_utf8(&buf[..=i]) {
                return slice.chars().next();
            }
        }
        None
    }
}
```

This also works fine.

Now, I also wish to provide an `impl` for `SourceChars<&mut SourceBytes<S>>`, so that `SourceChars` can rely on the buffer provided by `self.0` (which, in this circumstance, is `&mut SourceBytes<S>`).

```rust
impl<S> SourceChars<&mut SourceBytes<S>>
where
    S: Iterator<Item = u8>,
{
    fn buffer(&mut self, count: usize) -> Option<&str> {
        // let mut src = self.0.by_ref();
        for byte_count in 0.. {
            let Some(buf) = self.0.buffer(byte_count) else {
                return None;
            };
            if let Ok(slice) = std::str::from_utf8(buf) {
                if slice.chars().count() >= count {
                    return Some(slice);
                }
            }
        }
        unreachable!()
    }
}
```

This `SourceChars<&mut SourceBytes<S>>::buffer` relies on `SourceBytes<S>::buffer` to actually buffer the bytes, but instead `SourceChars` behaves as a wrapper to change the interpretation of the iterator `S` from bytes to `char`s.

The problem is that `self.0` cannot be borrowed mutably more than once, and in the loop, the reference `&mut self.0` does not appear to be dropped by the compiler.

How can I implement this in such a way that `SourceChars` relies on `SourceBytes::buffer` without running into this compiler error?

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self.0` as mutable more than once at a time
   --> src/parser/iter.rs:122:29
    |
119 |     fn buffer(&mut self, count: usize) -> Option<&str> {
    |               - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
122 |             let Some(buf) = self.0.buffer(byte_count) else {
    |                             ^^^^^^ `*self.0` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
...
127 |                     return Some(slice);
    |                            ----------- returning this value requires that `*self.0` is borrowed for `'1`
```

Comment: This is a known limitation in the borrow checker (see [Why does rust consider borrows active in other branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68262927/why-does-rust-consider-borrows-active-in-other-branches)).

Comment: @cdhowie I tried to find a workaround myself using `polonius-the-crab`, but do you have any suggestions? I want to provide this API to my future self, I know that I will use it a lot and my entire design hinges on this. So if there is an unsafe way to do it, I'm all ears, but I don't want to try writing unsafe code without guidance. Every time I do, someone tells me it is wrong.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3db2403c859a17c93c4352806c32e98b

Comment: Shouldn't the buffer be `VecDeque` and you should pop from the beginning?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Just discovered this bug :( Thanks for giving me the solution just in time!

Comment: @ChayimFriedman `VecDeque::get` is not the same as `Vec::get`. The latter takes a `Range` and the former takes a `usize`. This complicates my impl. Do you know much about `VecDeque`? Why is `get` for each a different signature?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman It would appear that `VecDeque` is not contiguous in memory, which is why it cannot provide a slice to its items. I would have to use `VecDeque::make_contiguous` beforehand, which is an unfortunate overhead.

Comment: `let Some(buf) = x else { return None; };` is a very verbose way of saying `let buf = x?;` in your last attempt.

Comment: You can of course also use `Vec` and `splice()` in the middle, but it will be less efficient (although I'm not sure it'll be less efficient if you call `make_contiguous()` anyway).

Comment: @cafce25 This is because I was previously attempting to solve this problem using `polonius-the-crab`, which at the time did not support `?` for `Option`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option that I previously tried was the crate [`polonius-the-crab`](https://docs.rs/polonius-the-crab/latest/polonius_the_crab/), but that ended up causing more problems with the usage of the API, in addition to making trait bounds difficult to get right.

Because of this inconvenience, I ended up using an unsafe pointer coercion to reduce the lifetime of the `buf` to no longer be dependent upon the `&mut SourceBytes`.

```rust
impl<S> Buffered for SourceChars<&mut S>
where
    for<'a> S: Iterator<Item = u8> + Buffered<ItemSlice<'a> = &'a [u8]> + 'a,
{
    type ItemSlice<'items> = &'items str where Self: 'items;

    // Allowed specifically here because the borrow checker is incorrect.
    #[allow(unsafe_code)]
    fn buffer(&mut self, count: usize) -> Option<Self::ItemSlice<'_>> {
        for byte_count in 0.. {
            let buf = self.0.buffer(byte_count)?;
            // SAFETY:
            //
            // This unsafe pointer coercion is here because of a limitation
            // in the borrow checker. In the future, when Polonius is merged as
            // the de-facto borrow checker, this unsafe code can be removed.
            //
            // The lifetime of the byte slice is shortened to the lifetime of
            // the return value, which lives as long as `self` does.
            //
            // This is referred to as the "polonius problem",
            // or more accurately, the "lack-of-polonius problem".
            //
            // <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54663>
            let buf: *const [u8] = buf;
            let buf: &[u8] = unsafe { &*buf };

            if let Ok(slice) = std::str::from_utf8(buf) {
                if slice.chars().count() >= count {
                    return Some(slice);
                }
            }
        }
        unreachable!()
    }
}
```

Additionally, here are the tests that show usage of the API. Using the `polonius-the-crab` crate failed to solve some lifetime issues that I ran across while implementing these tests.

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::{Buffered, SourceBytes, SourceChars};

    #[test]
    fn test_source_chars() {
        let source = "abcdefg";
        let chars = SourceChars::new(source.bytes());
        assert_eq!(source, chars.collect::<String>());
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_source_chars_buffer() {
        let source = "abcdefg";
        let mut bytes = SourceBytes::new(source.bytes());
        let mut chars = SourceChars::new(&mut bytes);
        // Ensure that the `buffer` function works.
        assert_eq!(&source[0..3], chars.buffer(3).unwrap());
        // Ensure that the characters are taken from the buffer,
        // and that `buffer` correctly preserves them.
        assert_eq!(&source[0..4], chars.by_ref().take(4).collect::<String>());
        // Ensure that the iterator has been advanced.
        assert_eq!(&source[4..7], chars.buffer(3).unwrap());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The workaround is as usual with all Polonius problems: repeat the calculation. It's less efficient, but it works.

```rust
impl<S> SourceChars<&mut SourceBytes<S>>
where
    S: Iterator<Item = u8>,
{
    fn buffer(&mut self, count: usize) -> Option<&str> {
        // let mut src = self.0.by_ref();
        for byte_count in 0.. {
            let Some(buf) = self.0.buffer(byte_count) else {
                return None;
            };
            if let Ok(slice) = std::str::from_utf8(buf) {
                if slice.chars().count() >= count {
                    return Some(std::str::from_utf8(self.0.buffer(byte_count).unwrap()).unwrap());
                }
            }
        }
        unreachable!()
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is not a the solution I like, it is a valid solution. Thank you.

Comment: Note that efficiency may be improved by using `from_utf8_unchecked` the second time since you already know that the buffer contains valid UTF8.

Comment: Not also that it's perfectly possible that the duplication will be removed by some optimisation pass. cargo-show-asm is a nice tool to check exactly what is generated